# find command with type and max date age

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, command

Is there a find command flag where I can set a max date age for files.  Example would be only files within the last 2 days

Also, a command I was given was `-type f` what does `-type f` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the manual ! See -mtime -2 to get the modifications in the last two days and only concerning the files with -type f

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html

Comment: I couldn't find the manual so I was using -help

Comment: Nearly every linux system has the online manual installed which you can access with the `man <command>` command. For the `find` command the manual becomes `man find` and the `man` command itself also comes with it's own manual: `man man`  -|- Women are unfortunately not documented though ;-)  `man woman` *"No manual entry for woman"*